# Redirecionar com mensagens de sucesso/erro

Tags: php

Na minha `home` tenho certas opções que dou ao utilizador. Cada opção tem como `action` um ficheiro em `.php`. Após a opção do utilizador ser submetida e validada pelo ficheiro `.php` eu mando o utilizador para a home redirecionado com uma mensagem de sucesso ou erro, exemplo: `home.php?sucesso=1`

As opções que o utilizador tem na home, tem também nas outras páginas.
Agora da maneira que tenho, o utilizador se clicar numa opção numa página diferente da `home` ele é redirecionado para a `home` e não para a página onde ele clicou na opção.

Terei que duplicar estes ficheiros `.php` de `action` onde valido as opções do utilizador e em cada um desses ficheiros`.php` redirecionar para a página que eu quero? Parece me errado.

Como poderei resolver da melhor maneira esta situação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a seguinte função

```
$patual = end(explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

O server php self, pegará o nome da página atual, sem contar os caminhos (devido ao explode e end).

Você então deverá fazer o seguinte:
Coloque a variavel em seu código php, e na parte de redirecionamento, troque o link para a variável. Exemplo:

```
<a href="./<?php echo $patual; ?>/?sucesso=1">
```

Se você estiver na home, o navegador lerá o código da seguinte maneira:

> `<a href="./home.php?sucesso=1">`

Se estiver na página perfil (exemplo, apenas ein?) O navegador lerá:

> `<a href="./perfil.php?sucesso=1">`

Coloquei com o a href só como exemplo. Ele funcionará perfeitamente com o location, ou outros.
Espero que tenha entendido. Desculpe se embolei, sinta-se à vontade para comentar

Comment: eu acho q é isso mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta :D

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar.